# ElasticSearch & NEST 6.x: Mapping a complex object to String

Tags: elasticsearch, nest, elasticsearch-6

I'm trying to setup an index in elasticsearch and running into an issue with a child object.

Given the following:

```
public class VersionNo
{
    public string Major { get; set; }
    public string Minor { get; set; }
    public string Build { get; set; }
    public string Revision { get; set; }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return $"{Major}_{Minor}_{Build}_{Revision}";
    }
}

public class Workflow
{
    public string Id { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }

    public VersionNo VersionNo { get; set; }
}
```

How would I construct a fluent mapping for Workflow.VersionNo so that the index ended up with "Major.Minor.Build.Revision"? In the example below I can't figure out how to setup "versionNo" to properly combine the child fields...

```
.Mappings(ms => ms
                .Map<Workflow>(m => m
                    .Properties(props => props
                        .Text(t => t
                            .Name("name")
                        )
                        .Text(t => t
                            .Name("versionNo")
                        )
                        .Text(t => t
                            .Name("id")
                        )
                    )
                )
            )
```

Answer (score 0):

You will need to tell NEST how to serialize `VersionNo` so that an instance of the type is serialized as a string. The most straightforward way to do this would be to

1. Add nuget package [NEST.JsonNetSerializer](https://www.nuget.org/packages/NEST.JsonNetSerializer/)
2. [Hook up the `JsonNetSerializer` in NEST.JsonNetSerializer package](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/net-api/current/custom-serialization.html#_jsonnetserializer) so that Json.NET is the serializer used by NEST for your documents
3. Write a [custom `JsonConverter`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/CustomJsonConverter.htm) for `VersionNo` that knows how to serialize `VersionNo` to a string value, and how to read a string value into a `VersionNo`

---

Alternatively, You could just define a string *property* on `VersionNo` that concatenates the value as the overridden `ToString()` method does. This property can then be mapped in Elasticsearch, in addition to `Major`, `Minor`, `Build` and `Revision` properties. With this approach, you can search on any of the properties, because each will be indexed.